# How to build BLAS and LAPACK for use in C++ on Linux cluster?

Tags: c++, linux, lapack, blas

I have a large computational problem I am working on. To decrease the computation speed of a set of linear equations in a square matrix, I have made use of `lapack` and `blas`. To get the libraries on my laptop (Ubuntu 2020) I ran the following command

```
sudo apt-get install libblas-dev liblapack-dev
```

Then I linked the code at compile by entering the following

```
g++ main.cpp -llapack -lblas
```

**However**, the cluster I am working on does not seem to have both of the libraries installed. It is much slower on the cluster, but yet a better chip. It runs, so I think it has the `lapack` libraries installed, but not `blas`. I'd like to install both.

### How would I build and compile the `lapack` and `blas` libraries with **neither** access to root nor `apt-get`?

Here is a short script for testing.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

extern "C" void dgesv_( int *n, int *nrhs, double  *a, int *lda, int *ipiv, double *b, int *lbd, int *info  );

int main() {
    int SIZE = 3;
    int nrhs = 1; // one column in b
    int lda = SIZE;
    int ldb = SIZE;
    std::vector<int> i_piv(SIZE, 0);  // pivot column vector
    int info;
    std::vector<double> A(SIZE*SIZE, 0); // sq mat with 0's
    A = {5, 2, 8, 9, 7, 2, 10, 3, 4};
    std::vector<double> b(SIZE);
    b = {22, 13, 17};

    dgesv_( &SIZE, &nrhs, &*A.begin(), &lda, &*i_piv.begin(), &*b.begin(), &ldb, &info );
    return 0;
}
```

I'd like to build this with

```
g++ main.cpp -L/path/to/lapack -L/path/to/blas -llapack -lblas
```

where the b matrix is replaced with the solution, and the solution is `1.71, 1.29, 0.18` (which is sort of arbitrary so I'm not providing the "print_matrix" function in the code to reduce clutter).

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### BLAS

- Download the latest version of  [BLAS](http://www.netlib.org/blas/)
- Open a terminal and go to the directory where you have it saved

```
tar -xvf blas-3.8.0.tgz  # unzip the blas source files
cd BLAS-3.8.0/ 
make
mv blas_LINUX.a libblas.a
mv *.a path/to/lib  # move the blas lib to the library you will be including at compile
```

---

### LAPACK

- Download the latest version of [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/)

```
tar -xvf lapack-3.9.0.tar.gz
cd lapack-3.9.0/
cp make.inc.example make.inc  # use example make as make
make
cp *.a path/to/lib
```

---

Now that the libraries have been built, and are stored in `path/to/lib`, the short example code in the question can be compiled.

```
g++ main.cpp -L/path/to/lib -llapack -lblas -lgfortran  # compiles the code
./a.out  # runs the code
```

Comment: NOTE: Using OpenBLAS, rather than Netlib's BLAS will result in significantly improved performance.

Comment: If your final target is a shared library, make sure to include `-fPIC` flag in make.inc `FFLAGS` and `FFLAGS_NOOPT`. The make process for lapack can take a while.

Answer (score 2):

You can clone official repo to your cluster via git:

```
git clone https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS.git
```

now cd to clonned repo, compile and install it:

```
cd OpenBLAS
make 
make install PREFIX=~/blas
```

Now you can link BLAS this way:

```
g++ main.cpp -L~/blas/lib -lblas
```

More info about compiling BLAS can be found in [official repo](https://github.com/xianyi/OpenBLAS).
Same for [LAPACK](https://github.com/Reference-LAPACK/lapack).

According to `README.md` from repo, LAPACK can be compiled with CMAKE:

```
cd lapack
mkdir build
cd build
cmake -DCMAKE_INSTALL_LIBDIR=/home/user/lapack ..
cmake --build . -j --target install
```

Comment: What does the ~ thing do here?

Comment: ~ is home directory of your current user. You can specify full path, like this `/home/user/blas/` instead

Comment: Thanks. @Aleksey the instructions you gave only work for `blas` and not `lapack`. When I run `make` inside of the lapack folder, it gives an error message. Any ideas?

Comment: Updated answer with LAPACK comilation example

Comment: Now I'm getting all kinds of undefined reference errors when I include the lapack library.